# GeckoFx can only be called from the same thread on which it was initialized (normally the UI thread)

Tags: c#, multithreading, gecko, geckofx

GeckoBrowserForm clasc

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
            {
        m_GeckoWebBrowser.Parent = this;
                        m_GeckoWebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                        m_GeckoWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, ee) =>
                        {
                            GeckoHtmlElement element = null;
                            var geckoDomElement = m_GeckoWebBrowser.Document.DocumentElement;
                            if (geckoDomElement != null && geckoDomElement is GeckoHtmlElement)
                            {
                                element = (GeckoHtmlElement)geckoDomElement;
                                DocumentDomHtml = element.InnerHtml;
                            }

                            if (m_Url.Equals(m_GeckoWebBrowser.Document.Url.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                Done = true;
                            }
                        };

                        m_GeckoWebBrowser.Navigate(m_Url);
    }

private static void InitializeXulRunner(string path)
        {
            if (s_IsXulrunnerInitialized)
            {
                return;
            }

            s_IsXulrunnerInitialized = true;
            Xpcom.Initialize(path);
        }

public GeckoBrowserForm(string xulRunnerPath, string url)
        {
            InitializeXulRunner(xulRunnerPath);
            m_Url = url;
            //FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            Location = new Point(0, 0);
            Size = new Size(800, 800);
            Done = false;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

and in other class I call form:

```
using (GeckoBrowserForm geckoBrowserForm = new GeckoBrowserForm(XulRunnerPath, propertyBag.ResponseUri.ToString()))
            {
                //geckoBrowserForm.CreateControl();
                geckoBrowserForm.Show();
                while (!geckoBrowserForm.Done)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }

                propertyBag.GetResponse = () => new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(geckoBrowserForm.DocumentDomHtml));
                //geckoBrowserForm.Dispose();
                base.Process(crawler, propertyBag);
            }
```

but I always get

> GeckoFx can only be called from the same thread on which it was
>   initialized (normally the UI thread).

in `m_GeckoWebBrowser`

What can I do? Ir was working with old `Skybound.Gecko` but not with new `GeckoFx`

Answer (score 0):

`Geckofx` does not support `multithread` , because as you mentioned its working on UI thread. But you can try it by following code :

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
 //What you want gecko browser to do! Like:
   using (GeckoBrowserForm geckoBrowserForm = new GeckoBrowserForm(XulRunnerPath, propertyBag.ResponseUri.ToString()))
        {
            //geckoBrowserForm.CreateControl();
            geckoBrowserForm.Show();
            while (!geckoBrowserForm.Done)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            propertyBag.GetResponse = () => new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(geckoBrowserForm.DocumentDomHtml));
            //geckoBrowserForm.Dispose();
            base.Process(crawler, propertyBag);
        }
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for idea but BeginInvoke can not be used in class. This code is in class not in form class.

Comment: different gecko browsers and yes I am calling Form from a class. I am calling Form like using (GeckoBrowserForm geckoBrowserForm = new GeckoBrowserForm(XulRunnerPath, propertyBag.ResponseUri.ToString())) {

Comment: Pass the SynchronizationContext of the UI thread to your thread and use that to make callback to the UI thread using SynchronizationContext.Post or SynchronizationContext.Send.

Comment: @Tom hmm I try but don't know how. Can you give me an example